# Find and replace a file in all the subdirectories

Tags: linux, terminal, find-and-replace

I'm new to linux. Using the terminal, i want to find and replace test.exe file with a modified file in all the sub directories of a directory called "abc". (The new modified file will have the same name as well test.exe).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`find ./ -type f -name test.exe --exec cp -y /newtest.exe {} \;`

Comment: feel free to help/answer...or start your own question :P    noted, edited. I'd think not following symlinks is desirable behaviour in this instance and default for find.

Comment: Don't add extra info in the comments, That is not what the comments are for, [edit] and update your answer instead

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario you want to use the following command from within the "abc" directory:

```
find . -type f -name test.exe -exec cp /path/of/new/test.exe {} \; -exec chmod g+rx {} \;
```

(Note the additional chmod command for illustration.)

Or, you might possibly want to (re)place the file in only "bin" subdirectories:

```
find . -type d -name bin -exec cp /path/of/new/test.exe {} \;
```